# Marklogic Forest Fragment data

Tags: marklogic

Is there any chance of retrieving the forest id and the data information that is extracted in expanded tree cache while posting the query request to the application server in marklogic? I have tried looking into Meteres database and using the xdmp:server-status api but no luck at this end to get the information

Answer (score 1):

xdmp:document-forest("/example.xml") returns the forest id of the document, example.xml

Comment: Actually i need to find which documents are being retrieved from expanded tree cache and which documents are retrieved from disk?